# iPad HTML Prototype: Which JS Framework?

Tags: javascript, html, css, prototype, ipad

are there any Javascript frameworks (such as iUI) available for building iPad prototypes?
I have found nothing useful so far.

Best,

Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Sorry just realised you were looking for iPad rather than iPhone/iPod. Adlib is useful as it has all the gestures built into the JavaScript library but it is an Apple tool that has not been released into the wild. There are some reverse engineer hacks out there if you want to play and Apple may well combine it with SproutCore (so the rumors go) The other tools are worth keeping an eye on as they may well morph and cater for both platforms.

Quick Con nect — All singing all danc ing. Will cre ate for a range of mobile devices but because of that is more com plex, i.e. more mov ing parts, than a more sim ple html/css/javascript aimed frame work tar get ing the iPhone. How ever well doc u mented and has an Addi son Wes ley book cov er ing major parts of it and if your brief is to dela with mul ti ple devices you will need to look at this.

iWebKit — Aimed at iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad and is in the html/css/javascript mould. Looks very powerful and well maintained.

WebApp​.Net — Aimed at iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad and is in the html/css/javascript mould.
iUi — Prob a bly one of if not the first frame work to emerge. Aimed at iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad and is in the html/css/javascript mould. Code is good and easy to use. I have built one project deliv ered to a pay ing cus tomer in this frame work. cur rency convertor

jQtouch — is a sub set of the jQuery JavaScript library and from that point of view has a lot going for it. Aimed at iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad and is in the html/css/javascript mould. Looks very pow er ful and well main tained. Also is fea tured in an O’Reilly book.

Phone Gap — cover iPhone, Android, Palm, Sym bian and Black berry - looks like a mix of dif­fer ent technolo gies, i will need to dig into it a bit more.

Mono Touch C# and .NET based appli ca tions and libraries that run on Apple’s iPhone and Apple’s iPod Touch devices, while tak ing advan tage of the iPhone APIs.
jQuery iPhone UI — Uses jQuery to build html/css/javascript based web sites.
Dash code — A toolkit from Apple for build ing html/css/javascript based wid get and other mac tools. Will now also build web sites for Safari and iXxx.

Xcode — Apple grand daddy of devel op ment uses objective-c and builds appli ca tions as opposed to web sites so really don’t belong here but of course allow the build ing of all thing iXxx.

Pastrykit — An inter nal toolkit used by Apple to make iPxxx based web sites. Not released to the pub lic but obvi ously an Ele phant in the room as it were.

To the above i would add
AdLib - Pastrykit for the iPad and probably aimed at interstitial iPad apps, but not released by Apple

Cappuccino - Objective-j so javascript looking like Xcode. There are some problems with this on mobile devices though in performance and memery terms.

Sproutcore - an html5 application framework which Apple may well adopt in their anti-flash battle

[More details](http://www.howitt.com/?p=222)

Answer (score 3):

and the new one from http://www.sencha.com/

but also take a look at http://dojotoolkit.org/features/mobile

Answer (score 2):

You could checkout http://www.jqtouch.com/ it's meant for iphone though...

Answer (score 1):

For fast and easy prototyping you can use our method TAP. It runs on the iPad, supports all transitions, swipes, rotation and a lot more. Perfect to show the concept of an interface or do a qualitative user test. Not good for presenting real data. http://unitid.nl/2011/03/touch-application-prototypes-tap-for-iphone-and-ipad-using-adobe-fireworks/